# nearrow with text on top

Tags: arrows

Instead of `A_n\nearrow A` producing
[image]

I would like a command `A_n\xnearrow{n\to\infty} A` producing something like [image]

where the arrow is tilted according to the length of the text above it. Does such a command exist or do you know of a way to define it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Formatting like `\lim`

Another idea using a formatting like it is done with `\lim`, because there is not much place above `\nearrow` and rotated text is more difficult to read:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\NEArrow}{\nearrow}

\begin{document}

  \[ A_n \NEArrow_{n\to\infty} A \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

### An attempt to improve Bernard's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/587127/16967):

- Vertical centering around the math axis via `\vcenter`.
- Smaller size for `n\to\infty` with detection of the current math style.
- Packed into a macro `\xnearrow[<below>]{<above>}`.

Example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{old-arrows}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\makeatletter
% \xnearrow[<below>]{<above>}
\newcommand*{\xnearrow}[2][]{%
  \mathchoice
  {\@xnearrow\scriptstyle{#1}{#2}}%
  {\@xnearrow\scriptstyle{#1}{#2}}%
  {\@xnearrow\scriptscriptstyle{#1}{#2}}%
  {\@xnearrow\scriptscriptstyle{#1}{#2}}%
}
% #1: math style
% #2: text below arrow
% #3: text above arrow
\newcommand*{\@xnearrow}[3]{%
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{30}{%
    $#1\xrightarrow[{#2}]{#3}\m@th$%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

  \[ A_n \xnearrow{n\to\infty} A \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Not sure it is exactly what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{old-arrows}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\begin{document}

    \[ A_n\rotatebox{30}{$\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}$} A\]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*: Loading  `relsize`, and using this code

```
\[ \mathlarger{A}_n\rotatebox{20}{$ \xrightarrow{\scriptscriptstyle n\to∞} $} \mathlarger{A} \]%
```

you obtain this variant:

[image]

Comment: it's very close but I don't want the arrow to leave the line as much

Comment: @ZachariasZarowski: Please see my edit, with a variant. Is it more as you want?

Answer (score 3):

You judge whether the output is really sensible and helpful for the reader.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}

\newcommand{\nearrowlim}[1]{%
  \mathrel{%
    \raise0.5ex\hbox{$
      \vcenter{\hbox{%
        \rotatebox{45}{$\xrightarrow{\scriptscriptstyle#1}$}%
      }}%
    $}
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\[
A_n \nearrowlim{n\to\infty} A
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @campa Thanks, I have added `origin=c` to the second variant of my answer.

Comment: @campa I tried that…